# How do I get to top questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, sitemap

How do you get to Top Questions on Stack Overflow? I got there once, and would like to go there again.

Comment: Do you mean the hot questions list?

Comment: Click the "Stack Overflow" logo on the main site; is that the "Top Questions" you're referring to?

Comment: You should note: you get different Sub Tabs on http://stackoverflow.com/ vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click questions and sort by votes https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes. That will give you the top-voted question on SO.

Bonus: Go to the last page to see the worst questions on SO (link will probably be invalid soon b/c of the pagination): https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=62239&sort=votes

Comment: Your "bonus" link is also a good place to go if you have some delete votes left over at the end of the day.